# Binomial Distribution Formula contains Combination function!

Tags: probability

why does the Binomial Distribution formula contain a combination function and not the permutation function when the order matters?

Answer (score 1):

When you expand $(x+y)^n$, you are simply interested in the coefficient in front of $x^{k}y^{n-k}$, i.e. how many times $x$ was chosen exactly $k$ times. But we are interested only in the number of times this happened when we foil, not in the order we choose those $x$'s and $y$'s.

Comment: Lets suppose, I toss a coin 4 times, the number of times i can get exactly 3 heads is 4 times:

**H,H,H,T
H,H,T,H
H,T,H,H
T,H,H,H**

Now as per your answer to the question we will consider these events as a single event while using the binomial distribution, which to my understanding is not the case. Your correction will be appreciated

Comment: All three are the single event of getting 3 heads (event is a subset of possible outcomes). That's why order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a simple explanation to it. The purpose of the presence of the combination function is to give a Multiplier which incorporates the effect of multiple possible arrangements. Yes Arrangements! Then why not the permutation formula?

Well Readers, if you can recall the permutation formula for the population having similar elements, you can understand. Binomial distribution formula is applicable only for the populations having 2 possible outcomes, either success or failure, which adds to the general permutation formula a denominator that converts the permutation to combination.

Mathematically:

General Permutation Formula:

```
                            **nPr= n! / (n-r)!**
```

Permutation formula for population with only 2 possible outcomes:
                              **nPr= n! /{(r!)(n-r)!}**

which is similar to the Combination formula. Hence, the binomial distribution formula contains the combination function.

Cheers!